# Can't get img to display from xml source using xsl attribute

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

My xsl file has this

```
    <img>
      <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="//movie[@num='1']/thumb_img1" width="100" height="111"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </img>
```

my xml file has

```
    <questions>
      <question>
       <movie num="0">
         <num>0</num>
         <quote>Xslt</quote>
         <title>movie</title>
         <thumb_img1>pic.jpeg</thumb_img1>
         <big_img>bigpic.jpeg</big_img>
       </movie>
```

when I run this I just get an x in a picture box when I use value-of it gives me the filename pic.jpeg which is what I want to use as the source for the picture

Comment: What do you "run this" with? No processor I know would allow your code to run without returning an error.

Comment: I open the xml with internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you wrote is *not* correct XSLT code. Using this code, you could never have transformed anything. The attributes `width` and `height` are not allowed on an `xsl:value-of` element.

Use an [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) instead of `xsl:attribute`.

```
<img src="{//movie[@num='1']/thumb_img1}" width="100" height="111"/>
```

Depending on the context of the `img` element in your code (the template match) you might not need to start the expression with `//`.